# Store one schema in multiple connections with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a User Schema and when i do a POST request i want the request to specify in which database the object will be stored.

I am trying to rewrite a Laravel API in which i just do

```
$user->setConnection("databaseName")->save();
```

I currently have the schema on a different .js file

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose has an API you can use to switch from one database to the other:

```
Connection.prototype.useDb()
```

More details about the method in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-useDb).

Calling that method returns a new mongoose connection with which you can use to perform database queries on the selected database. Using multiple connections in mongoose can be tricky but there is a very good doc on [handling multiple connections here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections).